# the pagination of my html table is not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

im trying to use pagination for an html page, but it isnt showing.

Here is my code:

```js
$('.datatable').dataTable({
  "sPaginationType": "bs_four_button"
});
$('.datatable').each(function() {
  var datatable = $(this);
  // SEARCH - Add the placeholder for Search and Turn this into in-line form control
  var search_input = datatable.closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('div[id$=_filter] input');
  search_input.attr('placeholder', 'Search');
  search_input.addClass('form-control input-sm');
  // LENGTH - Inline-Form control
  var length_sel = datatable.closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('div[id$=_length] select');
  length_sel.addClass('form-control input-sm');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/datatables/datatables.css">

<div id="wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>A demo of Bootstrap data table</h3>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="datatable table table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Rendering engine</th>
          <th>Browser</th>
          <th>Platform(s)</th>
          <th>Engine version</th>
          <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="gradeX">
          <td>Trident</td>
          <td>
            Internet Explorer 4.0
          </td>
          <td>Win 95+</td>
          <td class="center">4</td>
          <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeC">
          <td>Trident</td>
          <td>Internet Explorer 5.0</td>
          <td>Win 95+</td>
          <td class="center">5</td>
          <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Trident</td>
          <td>Internet Explorer 5.5</td>
          <td>Win 95+</td>
          <td class="center">5.5</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Trident</td>
          <td>Internet Explorer 6</td>
          <td>Win 98+</td>
          <td class="center">6</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Trident</td>
          <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
          <td>Win XP SP2+</td>
          <td class="center">7</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Trident</td>
          <td>AOL browser (AOL desktop)</td>
          <td>Win XP</td>
          <td class="center">6</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Gecko</td>
          <td>Firefox 1.0</td>
          <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
          <td class="center">1.7</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Gecko</td>
          <td>Firefox 1.5</td>
          <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
          <td class="center">1.8</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Gecko</td>
          <td>Firefox 2.0</td>
          <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
          <td class="center">1.8</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Gecko</td>
          <td>Firefox 3.0</td>
          <td>Win 2k+ / OSX.3+</td>
          <td class="center">1.9</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Gecko</td>
          <td>Camino 1.0</td>
          <td>OSX.2+</td>
          <td class="center">1.8</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Gecko</td>
          <td>Camino 1.5</td>
          <td>OSX.3+</td>
          <td class="center">1.8</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Gecko</td>
          <td>Netscape 7.2</td>
          <td>Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2</td>
          <td class="center">1.7</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Gecko</td>
          <td>Netscape Browser 8</td>
          <td>Win 98SE+</td>
          <td class="center">1.7</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Gecko</td>
          <td>Netscape Navigator 9</td>
          <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
          <td class="center">1.8</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Gecko</td>
          <td>Mozilla 1.0</td>
          <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
          <td class="center">1</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Gecko</td>
          <td>Mozilla 1.1</td>
          <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
          <td class="center">1.1</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Gecko</td>
          <td>Mozilla 1.2</td>
          <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
          <td class="center">1.2</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Gecko</td>
          <td>Mozilla 1.3</td>
          <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
          <td class="center">1.3</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Gecko</td>
          <td>Mozilla 1.4</td>
          <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
          <td class="center">1.4</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Gecko</td>
          <td>Mozilla 1.5</td>
          <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
          <td class="center">1.5</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Gecko</td>
          <td>Mozilla 1.6</td>
          <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
          <td class="center">1.6</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Gecko</td>
          <td>Mozilla 1.7</td>
          <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
          <td class="center">1.7</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Gecko</td>
          <td>Mozilla 1.8</td>
          <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
          <td class="center">1.8</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Gecko</td>
          <td>Seamonkey 1.1</td>
          <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
          <td class="center">1.8</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Gecko</td>
          <td>Epiphany 2.20</td>
          <td>Gnome</td>
          <td class="center">1.8</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Webkit</td>
          <td>Safari 1.2</td>
          <td>OSX.3</td>
          <td class="center">125.5</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Webkit</td>
          <td>Safari 1.3</td>
          <td>OSX.3</td>
          <td class="center">312.8</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Webkit</td>
          <td>Safari 2.0</td>
          <td>OSX.4+</td>
          <td class="center">419.3</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Webkit</td>
          <td>Safari 3.0</td>
          <td>OSX.4+</td>
          <td class="center">522.1</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Webkit</td>
          <td>OmniWeb 5.5</td>
          <td>OSX.4+</td>
          <td class="center">420</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Webkit</td>
          <td>iPod Touch / iPhone</td>
          <td>iPod</td>
          <td class="center">420.1</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Webkit</td>
          <td>S60</td>
          <td>S60</td>
          <td class="center">413</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Presto</td>
          <td>Opera 7.0</td>
          <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
          <td class="center">-</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Presto</td>
          <td>Opera 7.5</td>
          <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
          <td class="center">-</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Presto</td>
          <td>Opera 8.0</td>
          <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
          <td class="center">-</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Presto</td>
          <td>Opera 8.5</td>
          <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
          <td class="center">-</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Presto</td>
          <td>Opera 9.0</td>
          <td>Win 95+ / OSX.3+</td>
          <td class="center">-</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Presto</td>
          <td>Opera 9.2</td>
          <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
          <td class="center">-</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Presto</td>
          <td>Opera 9.5</td>
          <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
          <td class="center">-</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Presto</td>
          <td>Opera for Wii</td>
          <td>Wii</td>
          <td class="center">-</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Presto</td>
          <td>Nokia N800</td>
          <td>N800</td>
          <td class="center">-</td>
          <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td>Presto</td>
          <td>Nintendo DS browser</td>
          <td>Nintendo DS</td>
          <td class="center">8.5</td>
          <td class="center">C/A<sup>1</sup></td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Rendering engine</th>
          <th>Browser</th>
          <th>Platform(s)</th>
          <th>Engine version</th>
          <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/datatables/datatables.js"></script>
```

i already tried to use other versions of bootstrap but that didnt seem to help. the css works fine tho.
the code is from this site: "https://www.jquery-az.com/boots/demo.php?ex=39.0_1"
does anybody know why it isnt showing?

Comment: Hi PJ, your code looks OK, can you check the network tab to ensure that you are downloading the correct scripts? As a tip: place your script tags all the way up the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, I think your bootstrap and datatables references are out of date.

Just replace your `<link>` tags to this at the top:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></style>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and replace your `<script>` tags at the bottom to:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and under the `<script>` tags, add your `<script>` tag for your JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
            $('.datatable').dataTable();    
            $('.datatable').each(function(){
                var datatable = $(this);
                // SEARCH - Add the placeholder for Search and Turn this into in-line form control
                var search_input = datatable.closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('div[id$=_filter] input');
                search_input.attr('placeholder', 'Search');
                search_input.addClass('form-control input-sm');
                // LENGTH - Inline-Form control
                var length_sel = datatable.closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('div[id$=_length] select');
                length_sel.addClass('form-control input-sm');
            });
</script>
```

Just changing this line:

```
$('.datatable').dataTable({
                "sPaginationType": "bs_four_button"});
```

to:

```
$('.datatable').dataTable();
```

That should allow your pagination to display properly.